# JTabbedPane + JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Мне нужен JFrame, в нем 2шт JTabbedPane, в каждой из которых есть много JPanel, а самое главное - вертикальный скролл.

Причем панели в каждой вкладе должны иметь возможность размещаться посредством метода setBounds.

Я нарисовал картинку, чтобы было нагляднее. Кто-нибудь сможет показать мне, как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вот набросал вариант реализации

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestFrame2 extends JFrame {
    private JTabbedPane tabs;
    private Tab tab1;
    private Tab tab2;


    public TestFrame2() throws HeadlessException {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("tab1",10);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            tab1.addPanel(new InnerPanel());
        }

        Tab tab2 = new Tab("tab2",1);
        tabs.addTab(tab1.getTabName(),tab1);
        tabs.addTab(tab2.getTabName(),tab2);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(tabs,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private class Tab extends JPanel{

        private String tabName;
        private JScrollPane scroll;
        private JPanel dataPanel;

        public Tab(String tabName,int panels) {
            this.tabName = tabName;

            dataPanel = new JPanel();
            dataPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(700,Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            dataPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(dataPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            scroll = new JScrollPane(dataPanel);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(scroll);
        }

        public String getTabName() {
            return tabName;
        }

        public void addPanel(JPanel panel){
            dataPanel.add(panel);
        }
    }

    private class InnerPanel extends JPanel{

        private JPanel data;

        public InnerPanel() {

            data = new JPanel();
            Dimension dimData = new Dimension(700,100);
            data.setMinimumSize(dimData);
            data.setMaximumSize(dimData);
            data.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new VerticalIndent(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(new VerticalIndent(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(new HorizontalIndent(),BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(new HorizontalIndent(),BorderLayout.EAST);
            add(data,BorderLayout.CENTER);

            Dimension d = new Dimension(700,200);
            setMinimumSize(d);
            setPreferredSize(d);
            setMaximumSize(d);

        }

        private class VerticalIndent extends JPanel{
            public VerticalIndent() {
                Dimension dim = new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE,50);
                setMinimumSize(dim);
                setMaximumSize(dim);
            }
        }

        private class HorizontalIndent extends JPanel{
            public HorizontalIndent() {
                Dimension dim = new Dimension(10,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                setMinimumSize(dim);
                setMaximumSize(dim);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        JFrame frame = new TestFrame2();
        frame.setSize(750,800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```